# How to read JSON file in Spark Scala?

Tags: json, dataframe, scala, file, apache-spark

I have a JSON file I want to read using Spark Scala, but when I read that file as DF it shows "_corrupt_record" column, and I tried all possible ways.

```scala
val df = spark.read
  .format("json")
  .option("multiline","true")
  .load("PATH")
```

```
+--------------------+
|     _corrupt_record|
+--------------------+
|                   {|
|    "name": "Candace|
|  "phone": "1-355...|
|  "email": "egest...|
|  "address": "160...|
|  "postalZip": "1...|
|  "rankings": "9,...|
|  "alphanumeric":...|
|                  },|
|                   {|
|  "name": "Grant ...|
|  "phone": "(884)...|
|  "email": "magna...|
|  "address": "P.O...|
| "postal Zip": "6...|
|  "rankings": "9,...|
|  "alphanumeric":...|
|                  },|
|                   {|
|    "name": "Patrice|
+--------------------+
```

Comment: Show us the code you wrote and the input JSON file.

Comment: val df = spark.read. format("json").option("multiline","true").load("PATH")

Comment: [
{
   "firstName": "Joe",
   "lastName": "Jackson",
   "gender": "male",
   "age": 28,
   "address": 
{
       "streetAddress": "101",
       "city": "San Diego",
      "state": "CA"
 },
   "phoneNumbers": 
       { "type": "home", "number": "7349282382" }
   
}
]

Answer (score 0):

Using the JSON example which you provided in the comments,

> [ { "firstName": "Joe", "lastName": "Jackson", "gender": "male", "age": 28, "address": { "streetAddress": "101", "city": "San Diego", "state": "CA" }, "phoneNumbers": { "type": "home", "number": "7349282382" } } ]

the following line works well:

```scala
val df = spark.read.json("your/path")
```

[image]